# Clear parent on text not working

Tags: parent

I created a very simple combined object of a cube, cone, and text.
I added them all to a parent under the text object.

Now, when I try to clear the parent, I can clear it for the cube and cone, but I can't clear the parent for the text.

Here is a screenshot.  You can see the text is still under the combined parent:
[image]

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: It doesn't look parented to anything

Comment: Aren't you confusing the text data with the text object? The object contains the data.

Comment: @L0Lock is totally right. If your text would be parent to anything, it wouldn't be seen under Scene Collection, but under Cone or cube like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMq2C.png, but maybe just share your blend file so we don't have to guess what you did... ;)

Comment: @Chris I am definitely misunderstanding something.  I assumed Blender would create a new parent object, but that is not what is happening.

Comment: @Chris, your comment illustrated my misunderstanding most clearly.  If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an object is parented to another, the outliner will show the object in the hierarchy like so:

[image]